# CMake's GLOB_RECURSE seems to recurse more than what I asked it to

Tags: cmake, glob

In my project, I have a subdir named `foo`, and I want a list of all `.cpp` files under `foo`, and its subdirectories. So - it's GLOB_RECURSE for me. Now, looking at the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob-recurse), I see the syntax is:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE <variable> [FOLLOW_SYMLINKS]
     [LIST_DIRECTORIES true|false] [RELATIVE <path>] [CONFIGURE_DEPENDS]
     [<globbing-expressions>...])
```

and in my case:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE my_list "foo/" "*.cpp")
```

Unfortunately, what I'm getting is the paths of all `.cpp` files in my *project* - not just in `foo/`. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the role of the `<path>` placeholder in the syntax. It is only relevant when using the `RELATIVE` keyword - and you aren't using `RELATIVE`.

Thus, what you've actually provided `GLOB_RECURSE` is *two* globbing expressions.

Strangely enough, each globbing expression is considered to contain *both* the root directory for recursion *and* the globbing pattern at the same time. In your case this would be:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE my_list "foo/*.cpp")
```

CMake will split that string up, so that it looks for `.cpp` files in all subdirectories of `foo/`.

Comment: [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob-recurse) you refers to has an example of a globbing expression: `/dir/*.py  - match all python files in /dir and subdirectories`. Not sure why using similar expression looks "strangely enough" for you. As for `<path>` argument, the documentation seems to be clear about its role: it is part of `RELATIVE` option.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I was not expecting CMake to break up a single string argument at the last `/` and use one part as the root and the other one as the pattern.

Comment: In your original call, `"foo/"` and `"*.cpp"` are **separate** globbing expressions. CMake firstly produces a list of files which matches the first expression, then it produces a list of files which matches the second expression. Then these lists are combined into the single list (via appending).

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Yes, that's what I found out the problem was. Perhaps I should clarify this in my answer.

Comment: Yes, now the answer has much more sense than it was.